# BCDboot gives me an error about not being able to open the BCD template, how do I fix this so that I can fix the booting of my windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, partitioning

It seems that my BCD file is either corrupted or has some other problem, when invoking (here N: was the drive name of the boot partition that I had chosen) "bcdboot C:\Windows /s N: /f ALL" I get the following error: "BFSVC error:could not open the BCD template store. Status = [c000015c]" when going to C:\Windows\System32\config there is a BCD-template that supposedly is used to recreate the BCD template in the Boot directory, going to such a directory that is a unnamed occult FAT32 partition that I have named N: and going to N:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot there is a BCD file there, I have saved the old BCD as BCD.bak and tried to create a new BCD, with BCDBOOT but still got the same error, although a new BCD was present at the N:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot folder, it still doesn’t work, so I think that the BCD-template was corrupted and is creating bad BCD in the boot directory, is there a way to repair this BCD-template file without a Windows install CD? And if it can be done only with a install CD what are the exact steps that one should take, and will this erase all my files or make all installed programs stop working?

Comment: Perhapa a third-party tool with GUI might help: https://alternativeto.net/software/easybcd/